# PHP Search Multidimensional Array for a Value and Return Key of Grandparent

Tags: php

I want to write a function that will search for a value in a multidimensional array and return the key of the grandparent.  Please see the array hierarchy below.

```
Array
(
[results] => Array
    (
        [quote] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [symbol] => VFORX
                            )
                        [LastTradePriceOnly] => 24.79
                    )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [symbol] => VGSTX
                            )
                        [LastTradePriceOnly] => 21.77
                    )
                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [symbol] => HPQ
                            )
                        [LastTradePriceOnly] => 21.00
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

For example, I want to search the 'symbol' key for value 'HPQ' and return either the LastTradePriceOnly value of 21.00 or the grandparent's key is [2].

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide on getting me started.

Comment: please start writing some code from your end so that we can suggest something

Comment: Yes, it is best for you to share code that you have tried.  This will help the community to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Hast's answer is the solution, but to add, you can get the 'grandparent' as well using the key of the array in the foreach statement. Cheers.

```
<?php

$array = array(); // this is your array
$value = 'HPQ';
$result = null;
$grandparent = null;

foreach($array['results']['quote'] as $quote_index => $quote) {
    if ($quote['@attributes']['symbol'] == $value) {
        $result = $quote['LastTradePriceOnly'];
        $grandparent = $quote_index;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you and Hast both.  This worked perfectly.  I will attempt to share my code in the future.